# Ffmpeg encoded video results in corrupted YouTube video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, youtube

I'm creating videos for YouTube that combine a still image with an MP3 file. For some reason, some of the videos get corrupted (in the example below after 15 seconds) and result into a gray screen. This is the `ffmpeg` command that I use:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i frame0043.png -i tts.mp3 -acodec copy -shortest -vf "subtitles=subs.srt:force_style='FontName=Poppins,FontSize=36,Bold=1',scale=1920:1080" video.mp4"
```

Here is the output:

```
  built with gcc 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59.  9.101 / 59.  9.101
  libavformat    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8.  9.100 /  8.  9.100
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'frame0028.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
[mp3 @ 000002c0a30b2980] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'tts.mp3':
  Duration: 00:05:01.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 160 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 160 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000002c0a33cdf00] libass API version: 0x1502000
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000002c0a33cdf00] libass source: commit: 0.15.2-11-g4c3ace7cdcc740652331dbd57cc500b4ad50be81
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000002c0a33cdf00] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.11 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 3.0.0 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000002c0a33cdf00] Using font provider directwrite (with GDI)
[libx264 @ 000002c0a245b400] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000002c0a245b400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000002c0a245b400] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000002c0a245b400] 264 - core 164 r3065 ae03d92 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.5.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.9.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 160 kb/s
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000002c0a33cdf00] fontselect: (Poppins, 700, 0) -> Poppins-Bold, 0, Poppins-Bold
```

Example video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7-hCObVKQU

Do you see anything out of the ordinary that might be causing the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the video fully play well locally?

Comment: Yeah it works fine locally.

Comment: @Gyan do you think it could have anything to do with the fact that the pixel format is yuv444p instead of yuv420p? I've been reading that 420 is the recommended format for YouTube.

Comment: Possibly, but since the initial 15 seconds were processed fine, not sure why it would fail in between. But can't hurt to check. Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`